# jQuery $.post and searching in the resulting HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.post(
    url,
    send_to,
    function(data) {
        console.log($(data).find("img");
    }
);
```

I'm getting some result from server and want to find the `src` value of `img` tag in that result HTML code, but it's not working.

How I can search for the `img` tag in the received data?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the code that you're receiving in the `data` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine. The [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) (`$(data)`) will turn a valid HTML string into a (decoupled) Node tree.

Be aware, though, that [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches through the *descendants* of the element or collection of elements on which it is called. If your `<img>` is in the top level of the HTML, use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead. For example:

```html
<!-- Returned HTML: -->
<p>Here's a nice image of a kitten:</p>
<img src="demonic_kitten.png" />
<p>Muhahahaha!</p>
```

```js
/* JavaScript (callback function): */
var success = function(data) {
    console.log($(data).filter("img");
};
```

If the `<img>` is not in the top level, make sure the data that is returned is valid HTML and contains an `<img>` in the first place.

Comment: Exactly! Nice answer...example HTML would be so helpful, instead of trying to answer all eventualities ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see where you might be going wrong without some idea of what the `data` variable contains in terms of HTML. If you're sure it's just an `IMG` tag that's being returned from the AJAX request, using `find` will attempt to search through your `IMG` tag for another `IMG` altogether, and should be adjusted to this:

```
console.log($(data).attr("src"));
```

If it's not just an `IMG` tag being returned in your HTML, and is a bunch of different tags, I would suggest wrapping your HTML in something like a `DIV` tag before it's sent back to the Javascript, for example if you're returning something like:

```
<p>Something</p>
<p>Something else</p>
<img src="something" />
<p>Something</p>
```

...rather return something like this:

```
<div>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something else</p>
    <img src="something" />
    <p>Something</p>
</div>
```

...which would also make your original code work. I would also think about adding the `dataType` option to your jQuery AJAX request:

```
$.post(
    url,
    send_to,
    function(data) {
        console.log($(data).find("img");
    },
    "html"
);
```

Hope this helps! :)